# Matrix generated by dynamic allocation have different address when accessed in void function

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a matrix through an array of addresses pointing to the other arrays.
When I execute the below code, I have a result I cannot understand.

The address printed out from `allocation` and a for loop in  `main` are same. However, `get_address` prints out the different address, even though it is doing exactly the same with the for loop in `main`.

```
void allocation(double **a, int rows, int columns){
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        a[i] = new double[columns];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void get_address(double *a, int rows, int columns){
    for (int i=0; i<rows; i++){
        cout << (&a)[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}


int main(){
    double *a;
    allocation(&a, 3, 3);
    get_address(a, 3, 3);

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        cout << (&a)[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
0x100106220 0x100106240 0x100106a50 
0x100106220 0x16fdfdcd0 0x1000031dc # this is different
0x100106220 0x100106240 0x100106a50
```

Why am I getting different addresses? Also, when I trying to assign numbers on `a` as

```
void assign_number(double *a, int rows, int columns){
    double **ptr = &a;
    for (int i=1; i<rows; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<columns; j++){
            ptr[i][j] = 1
        }
    }
}
```

This generates `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` error. Why accessing is problematic with this way?

Comment: Your code is UB. You access/set at `(&a)[1]`. This memory that isn't reserved for anything.

Comment: Side note : Why are you still using "C" style arrays? Passing pointers + sizes seperately is bound to result in bugs later.  Have a look at `std::vector<std::vector<double>>`. In current C++ you should [avoid the use of naked new/delete as much as possible](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r11-avoid-calling-new-and-delete-explicitly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> int main(){
>     double *a;
>     allocation(&a, 3, 3);
> ```

In t he above quoted snippet, `a` doesn't point to valid memory, so when you pass it into `allocation`, [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) occurs.

You can avoid this by actually allocating memory for `a`.

```
int main(){
    double a[3][3];
    allocation(&a, 3, 3);
```